# How to load a html file instantly into the textarea box using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, filereader

I want the html file to instantly load into the textarea without the user having to click on the button to do so. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `onchange` on your file:

```
document.getElementById("loadFile").onchange = function() {
    // ...
})
```